# What happens when two processes bind to a port and communicate with the same server?

Tags: networking

If two processes both use a shared local port to connect to the same remote port of the server server, what happens when the server tries to respond to one?  Or is there a mechanism to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're asking about TCP here. When the two processes connect to a single remote port, they will be using different local ports. That is how the server distinguishes the connections. A connection has four parts that uniquely identify it: source port, source IP address, destination port, and destination IP address.

Comment: I'm sorry, I must not have written very clearly.  I was asking what happens when both the local and remote endpoints are the same?

Comment: You can not have more than one TCP connection using the same local and remote ports. For example, in POSIX (Linux), the bind() call will fail with errno EADDRINUSE in the second process that tries to use the same local port. Note, it may be possible for two processes to share a single socket, but their reads/writes will be interleaved and the server will think there's only one client.